# manually increment id in c# from mysql

Tags: c#, mysql

So I have make an order management system I have use this code to insert my order in data.

```
xconn.Open();
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "insert into tblOrder  
(RegId,ItmId,quantity,Odrdate,Total) values ('" + label11.Text + "','" + 
26 + "','" + txt26.Text + "','" + date + "','" + lbltotal.Text + "');";
cmd.Connection = xconn;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
xconn.Close();
```

So the order id in my table is auto increment but I want it to only increment after one order is complete.

Once I click total the odrid should increment so that next order gets a new id.

Comment: your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks - someone could easily mess with your data. See http://bobby-tables.com/ for an explanation and some examples of how to do it correctly using parameterised queries and prepared statements. It also helps you avoid possible syntax errors when doing this naive concatenation of strings to build queries.

Comment: As to your question - if you do an INSERT, the field should auto-increment, assuming you set it up correctly. If you fetch the last inserted ID from the database immediately after you run the query, you can find out what value the latest ID is, if you need it. But there's not enough context about your mention of "click total". There's no button here. How does that relate to your code?

Comment: well i am using it for my college project and deadline is due tomorrow. so if you could help me in this code it'd be great :)

Comment: You've said what your code _should_ do, but not what the problem with it currently is. What's going wrong? Is it not creating the ID as you expected? And why shouldn't it create the Order ID until you "click total" (although we don't know what that actually does, or at what point in the process)? Once you have row in the DB, there'll be an ID, there's not really any harm in that. In fact it's a good thing. What's the real issue here?

Comment: Assuming the id is a primary key, you cannot insert a row without one. What constitutes a "complete" order? I think you are spending time on a non-problem.

Comment: the problem is if 3 or 4 items are being added in 1 order each item gets a new order id and my odrid is not a primary key so it can be repeated

Comment: That sounds like an Order-Item, not an order. You need to grab the id of the parent order (which should exist first) and use that to create the Order Item record. I don't know about MySql but it should have a way to get the id of an inserted row without querying the database for Max of last because that is unreliable.

Comment: Then you have a problem with your database structure. You need two tables - a master "Orders" table with unique ID, and any info which pertains to the entire order (e.g. user ID, delivery address, etc) and then "OrderItems" listing each product item (and probably things like the quantity and the price), with a foreign key to "Orders" (and, I guess, a foreign key to "Products").  Also there should be no need to store a "Total" field since it's trivial to compute when you need to use it, by summing the price of all the ordered items.

Comment: oh ok! i got it, but if you could give me any practical example it'd be much better.

Comment: It's a bit too broad really for an SO answer - it's basically a bit of a rewrite of your project, I would guess. I've given you the outline of the data structure. What you need to do after that is write the queries and tie them to the UI. Good luck. It looks like you basically know how to write queries. Find out how to get the last inserted ID (you'll need it when creating an order, so you can then create orderItems with the right OrderID). If you're not sure about the whole foreign key thing, then read up about entity-relationship design. And don't leave your assignments till the day before!

Comment: You might be able to Google and example, like maybe this: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-appsample-customers-orders-database

Comment: Okay. thanks for explaining :)

Answer (score 0):

You simply can not insert a new row into a database table without a unique id, if the id is the primary key.

Why dont you introduce a new column „order_status“ in which you store the state of the current order?

Answer (score 0):

> Once I click total the odrid should increment so that next order gets
>   a new id.

What if a orderId is exist for example you click on 993 and you want 994 but it's already exists in database.

As Other suggested you can put a column that have information regarding your +1.
If you are using your current code in production your code can easily hacked using SQL-Injection be careful.